# How can I trigger a build using a VCS trigger without checking out any files

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 8.1.2 and I need to trigger a build whenever someone checks a file in to a specific directory, but I DON'T want TeamCity to check the files out from that directory. I have a process that I need to run and I just need the triggering mechanism of TeamCity without the checkout mechanism.

I have a VCS Trigger set up and have tried adding some trigger rules that trigger a build when a file is checked in to my directory that I am monitoring, but that really only seems to work if you have checkout rules set up.

I have tried deleting all checkout rules, but TeamCity just tried to check out every file from the root.

I have tried adding an "exclude all" checkout rule (-:.), but then the build never get's triggered.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a build configuration with VCS checkout mode "Do not checkout automatically" and no checkout rules configured.

Comment: Additional question: are there any way to perform this for just one of a number of VCS roots? I have two roots, where I want to checkout one, but just use the other as a trigger..

Comment: It is not possible to specify different checkout modes for different VCS roots. As workaround you can create a build configuration with the second VCS root attached and checkout mode "Do not checkout automatically". And snapshot dependent build configuration which checkouts the first VCS root and has trigger with option "Trigger on changes in snapshot dependencies". So the second build configuration will trigger if there are changes in any repository.
Please vote for the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-8242.